# FileSaver.js with a dialog

Tags: javascript, client-side, filesaver.js

I am using the [FileSaver.js](https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/) to download file using the code below. This file is automatically downloaded to a default folder (Tested in Chrome), but I need to show a window dialog that says something like "Save as file...". Thanks!

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
saveAs(blob, "file.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to show a window dialog that says something like "Save as
>   file...". Thanks!

To solve your problem as a whole I recommend using a [prompt method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) which will prompt the user with a dialog to save the file name.

In addition, there are many libraries out there for custom dialogs as well like [AlertifyJS](https://alertifyjs.com/) or [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) which I used in my [Flat Design Character Maker](http://michaelsboost.github.io/Flat-Design-Character-Maker/).

Here's a simple example of the [prompt method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

```js
saveFile.onclick = function() {
  var filename = prompt("Define your file name.");
  if (filename) {
    alert("File saved!");
  } else {
    alert("Save canceled!");
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="saveFile">Save file</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

This dialog you are talking about is browser settings specific. Meaning in Google Chrome for example in `Settings/Advanced/Downloads` section you have a setting:

`Ask where to save each file before downloading` which you can set `true/false`.

If you disable this setting it would always ask you and bring the `SaveAs` dialog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you can set this option in the browser but the problem here is most people don't want to change their browser settings or even want to learn which doesn't necessarily solve this problem as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, according to this [github discussion](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/115), it is not possible.